# how to connect user vsftpd with domain

Tags: domain, ftp, vsftpd

Hi I am new to server management and I have purchased a vps from **digitalocean** but my main concern is that I have created a **vsftpd** for a user and I want my domain to point to the files uploaded in that user directory i.e. **home/user/project** which is the root directory for the user vsftpd connection. but my domain is pointing to default  **/var/www/html/**  directory.

kindly guide me to this process thanks.

Comment: Those files aren't served magically, if you control the webserver (Apache / nginx I assume), change the path. If you don't, I don't think the question belongs on SF.

Comment: i need guidance to where to put server related questions? yes I have access to apache. I am bit confused which approach shall I use because some forum suggest to create sub directory inside /var/www/ and then create virtual host and other what I have questioned above.